# How do i handle this error - HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#136)

Tags: visual-c++

```
void main(){
    char *p;
    p = new char[3];

    strcpy_s(p, sizeof(p), "AB");
    cout << p << endl << "input : ";
    cin.get(p, 3);

    delete []p;
}
```

Why does an error occurs in the 'delete'??

The errors do not occur elsewhere..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGf4i.jpg)

Comment: `sizeof(p)` is not the 'correct' statement in your `strcpy_s` - because `p` is a char*, so it will always give 4 or 8 depending on the architecture, not the size of the allocated array. Although, that doesn't explain your heap corruption.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito It's possible that `strcpy_s` zero-inits the whole buffer (perhaps only in debug builds). That would explain the overrun.

Comment: Not just possible, it is exactly what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my Igor's and Han's comments, it appears that using `sizeof(p)` in the `strcpy_s` function *is* actually your issue. `p` is a `char *`, doing `sizeof(p)` returns the size of the pointer (usually 4 or 8 depending on the architecture), not the size of the allocated array. In debug builds, the documentation for [strcpy_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx) states:

> The debug versions of these functions first fill the buffer with 0xFE. To disable this behavior, use _CrtSetDebugFillThreshold.

So, the runtime will fill 4 (or 8) bytes, which is larger than your allocated array into `p`, thus corrupting the heap.